# SQL Comparing 2 columns then changing the values in one dynamically

Tags: sql

I have a Query where i want it to display a range of dates, and in the next column have a count of when an event happens on a day.

At the minute i can display how many times an event happens on a day, but when i try to display all of the dates, they all display that 1 event happens on it.

I've tried doing Case's and If statements, but seem to get syntax errors

```
select distinct d.DateNumber, count(*) as AmountofEvents
from dbo.dateTable d
join dbo.TimeTaken m 
on d.dateNumber  = m.dateEventHappens or d.dateNumber != m.dateEventHappens
group by d.dateNumber, m.dateEventHappens
Order by d.dateValue ASC
```

DateNumber is the list of the dates, AmountofEvents is the count of events on that day and dateEventHappens is the day that has the event.

I need to get a way to compare when the dateNumber is not equal to dateEventHappens, and then display the AmountofEvents count as 0 for that day.

Comment: You rarely never need to combine GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: @nflint . . . Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the `GROUP BY`, remove the `SELECT DISTINCT`, and introduce `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select d.DateNumber, count(m.dateEventHappens) as AmountofEvents
from dbo.dateTable d left join
     dbo.TimeTaken m 
     on d.dateNumber = m.dateEventHappens 
group by d.dateNumber
order by d.dateValue ASC;
```